# Cannot delete capcity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to build some infrastructure using Terraform. This includes an ECS cluster and a capacity provider for said cluster.

The capacity provider was successfully created, but then I changed its name because I accidentally left it as "example". By changing the name, Terraform attempts to destroy the existing "example" capacity provider and create a new one.

Terraform fails with:

`The capacity provider cannot be deleted because it is associated with cluster: my-cluster. Remove the capacity provider from the cluster and try again.`

So I go to update the cluster in the console, and I remove the capacity provider from the cluster and save the cluster. Then, I try again, but it keeps failing with the same error message.

How can I possibly delete this capacity provider? Surely, this must be a bug in AWS?

Comment: Check other clusters. Also AWS sometimes does not remove things immediately. Wait a bit and check later.

Comment: It's the only cluster. I will wait a bit and check again later. Thanks!

Comment: You could try running `terraform apply --refresh-only` to get it to sync up with the latest state of your infrastructure.

Comment: You could also try `terraform state rm <capacity-provider-id>` to remove it from the Terraform state entirely, since you have deleted it manually already.

Answer (score 0):

While I had disassociated the capacity provider from the cluster, I hadn't deleted it, and it seems it was still considered associated for whatever reason. By actually deleting the capacity provider under the "Capacity Providers" tab of the cluster, I was able to proceed.